# C Makefile Conflicting Types Error on OSX

Tags: c, macos, makefile

I have been trying to compile C-code via a makefile on OSX Catalina but get errors.  **When I compile the code on Ubuntu it succeeds but on OSX I encounter the following error towards the end of compilation:**

```
gcc -c -ansi   -g scan-fct_pddl.tab.c
scan-fct_pddl.y:858:6: error: conflicting types for 'fcterr'
void fcterr( int errno, char *par ) {
     ^
scan-fct_pddl.y:174:3: note: previous implicit declaration is here
  fcterr( PROBNAME_EXPECTED, NULL ); 
  ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [scan-fct_pddl.tab.o] Error 1
```

I find it odd that this error is only thrown when compiling the code on OSX.  I've tried different versions of gcc and have also updated bison and flex but still encounter this error.

**Update**

Error fixed by changing the parameter names in the signatures of the forward declarations that mentioned conflicting types.  Make sure to match the new signature when the function is declared as well.

Comment: The compiler is trying to tell you that your code invokes fcterr() prior to having seen a definition of that. So it creates an implicit declaration which then conflicts later on when you actually provide that declaration. Two solutions for this: move your fcterr() method up prior to invocation (ugly, and often not practical/nice), or provide a forward declaration of the fcterr() method.  Why this didn't fail on Ubuntu may have to do with (default compiler flags

Comment: Thanks for the info; although I'd prefer not to change the source code I can see where I might be able to provide a forward declaration.  Would just altering the default compiler flags be a bad approach (and what specific flags)?

Comment: You'll have to look at the compiler flags and compare, it is unlikely that you will find a solution there but worth a try. Mod the source is more likely what you'll need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is calling the function `fcterr(PROBNAME_EXPECTED, NULL);` before it has been declared / defined. Sort of like this:

```
// trying to use this function before it has been declared / defined
fcterr( PROBNAME_EXPECTED, NULL ); 


// Later in the code it is defined here
void fcterr( int errno, char *par ) {
     // ...
}
```

Note: Implicit declarations in c have a return type of `int`, which is incompatible with your return type of `void`.

You can do one of two things:

Move the definition of the function before the usage

```
// Define the function here
void fcterr( int errno, char *par ) {
     // ...
}

// Now the compiler knows what this function is
fcterr( PROBNAME_EXPECTED, NULL );
```

Declare the function before the usage - usually this is done in a header file:

```
// Declare the function (this could/should go in a header)
void fcterr(int errno, char *par);

// Now the compiler knows what this function is
fcterr( PROBNAME_EXPECTED, NULL ); 

// Later in the code it is implemented here
void fcterr( int errno, char *par ) {
     // ...
}
```

I am surprised that you dont get this issue in your Ubuntu build - are you sure there is no difference between the two builds? - I doubt you can fix this by changing your makefile! - unless there is some information I am missing...

#### Update

It seems there is a bug in the code. You can un-comment `scan-fct_pddl.y` line ~101, where the author probably tried to declare his function:

```
/* declare funct */
void fcterr( int errnum, char *par );
```

Then later in the same file the function is declared (~line 878):

```
void fcterr( int errno, char *par ) {
}
```

Now the issue here is that by declaring the function at the top, we now get an error instead of a warning. This is because just above this function def (~line 867) they include `lex.fct_pddl.c` (puke), anyway, in that file about halfway down they include `errno.h` Notice that `errno` is also the name of the first parameter. In errno.h somewhere I believe `errno` is #define'd as something else - this is really bad now! - because the function the person wrote is now potentially different to how it looks like it should be.

A simple fix here is to re-name that parameter:

```
void fcterr( int errnum, char *par ) {
}
```

So un-comment the declaration at the top and re-name that parameter. That should fix *this* issue - and it *does* need fixing.

Comment: Thanks for the additional help; it is very odd but there is no difference between the source code I'm building on Ubuntu and OSX Catalina.  I've been downloading the source [here](https://fai.cs.uni-saarland.de/hoffmann/metric-ff.html).  I'm relatively new to C programming but more and more it seems like I might have to modify the source code in order to compile it on OSX (which seems odd).

Comment: So the exact same issue is there in ubuntu, but it is a warning and the compiler seems to make a best guess (and luckily get it right). Here is one (of maaaaaaany warnings) I see: `scan-fct_pddl.y: At top level:
scan-fct_pddl.y:878:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘fcterr’
 void fcterr( int errno, char *par ) {
      ^~~~~~
scan-fct_pddl.y:193:3: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘fcterr’ was here
   fcterr( PROBNAME_EXPECTED, NULL );`

Comment: Ok I think I got to the bottom of it - but this code base is a real nasty little mess! - see my update

Comment: Thanks a bunch for poking around in the code! I finally got it to compile by following your suggestions.  I'll briefly edit my post with the solution.

Comment: @BitStacker no problem, I was curious!, by the way you can declare the function signature at the top without any parameter names - sometimes it is useful to do this (perhaps like in this case so you don't have to change it in both places): `void fcterr( int, char *);` Note: this is just for the declaration at the top, not the implementation... although the function appears to have an empty body anyway - so you could do it in both places in this case :o